# rgamma function in R: scale as a vector

Tags: r, sampling, simulation, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to draw samples from Gamma distribution but I'm considering the 'scale' argument of `rgamma` as a vector because each sample unit has different scale parameters. I'd like to know what is the rule of this function to choose the values of the argument. For example, if I run this:

```
rgamma(10,shape=1,scale=1:10)
```

Is it generating `rgamma(1,shape=1, scale=10)`,$\ldots$,`rgamma(1,shape=1, scale=10)`? Besides that, what if I run this:

```
rgamma(1,shape=1,scale=1:10)
rgamma(2,shape=1,scale=1:10)
rgamma(11,shape=1,scale=1:3)
```

Which scale parameter is it choosing for each draw?
Could someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: @Pedro: Use `sapply`: `sapply(1:10, FUN=rgamma, shape=1, n=10)`. In this case, `1:10` are the scale values and the shape is 1 and $n$ is 10. This produces a 10x10 matrix with each column corresponding to one `scale` value.

Answer (score 2):

R has built-in vectorization. What this means for your first questions is that `rgamma(10, shape=1, scale=c(1:10))` will generate 10 values, one for each scale parameter.

When the number of rgamma calls is not the same as the length of the vector, like in `rgamma(11, shape=1, scale=c(1:3))`, R will *recycle the scale values in order* until it has 11 scale values of the form `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2)`.

Comment: ... and `rgamma(2,shape=1,scale=1:10)` will use the first 2 values of the `scale` parameter.